# Why does my transaction reverts when funding a VRFCoordinatorV2 subscription locally?

Tags: solidity, brownie, chainlink

I've been following the documentation on docs.chain.link: https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/examples/programmatic-subscription/
in order to have a programmatic way to handle a subscription. To fund the subscription the documentation says to write this kind of function:

```
function fundSubscription(uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {

    linkToken.transferAndCall(address(coordinator), amount, abi.encode(s_subscriptionId));
}
```

I modified this function a little bit and it looks like this:

```
function fundSubscription() public {

    linkToken.transferAndCall(address(coordinator), linkToken.balanceOf(address(this)), abi.encode(s_subscriptionId));
}
```

Instead of external onlyOwner it is just public, so that anyone can fund the subscription and instead of passing an amount, I just want to transfer the whole contract's balance to the subscription.
Obviously before calling `fundSubscription()` **I transferred to the contract a good amount of LINK token**, so that is not the problem.
The transaction reverts with a VirtualMachineError but nothing else is specified, so I can't tell what kind of error is this.

**Error outputs**:

*VirtualMachineError(ValueError({'message': 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert', 'stack': 'RuntimeError...c1c9b07ca57de0db5e968f553df052747dfdccf9d5bb6c5637348d', 'reason': None, 'error': 'revert', 'program_counter': 736}}}))*

*...........local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\transaction.py:446: VirtualMachineError*

I'm on a development chain (I'm using brownie with ganache-cli).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Davide, what are the values for coordinator and linkToken?  These are usually Chainlink Smart Contracts on the relevant testnet -- dont think they'd be available on your local testnet? For example the subscription account etc would not be available locally. While technically possible, I dont think it's feasible/usefuly for you to run the entire subscription management infrastructure locally on your dev machine.  See for info on subscriptions: https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/introduction/#subscriptions

Comment: Zeus I'm sorry, I solved the problem already a few days ago but for some reason, StackExchange didn't let me post the answer. I posted it now. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Well done! great to hear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling `fundSubscription()` function inside the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock instead of the `fundSubscription()` function inside my "own" contract.